# How can I stop an iPod from upgrading the iOS once it has already started the download?

Tags: ipod-touch, ios, ipod

I accidentally clicked to upgrade from iOS 7 to iOS 8.1.1. The problem is, I am a developer and want my device to remain at iOS 7 so I'm testing with the same OS and browser version that my corporate users are using in the field. However, there is no "Cancel" button (seriously, Apple? ...*seriously?* )

I tried shutting the device off and turning it back on, but it resumes the download after it's restarted. Same with turning WiFi on and off. I need to stop it permanently.

I read [this macworld.com article](http://www.macworld.com/article/2683693/how-to-upgrade-to-ios-8-and-downgrade-to-ios-7-if-you-regret-it.html) that discusses how to revert back once you've upgraded, but at the top it specifies that it no longer works: "Update: The technique outlined here for reverting to iOS 7 no longer works as Apple has stopped signing versions of iOS prior to iOS 8."

I did read one "hacky" way to prevent the download from completing by leaving the video recorder on so space fills up and it can't finish. Is there a better way to do it?

(Hopefully this question is in the right place w/right tags - I haven't posted in this SE before)

Comment: Finish the download, but do not install. then delete the file

Comment: I was under the assumption it'd install it automatically after downloading. (The WiFi in my office is super slow so it has ~8 hour download left. Guess I'll find out in the morning.) If I do have the option to download but not install, that's great!

Comment: assumes you have your setting to no auto updates.

Comment: I was unable to find the auto update setting you referred to. However, I came in this morning to an alert displayed, "Software Update Unavailable - Software Update is not available at this time. Try again later." However, the Software Update page says "Downloaded" and has an "Install Now" option. So... did it download fully or not? Did it in fact try to auto-install it and fail? Not sure what to think there. However it looks like I have an "out" now.

Comment: Either way, it's now irrelevant since our hardware team wants to do a mass update for all corporate users anyway, meaning I need to upgrade after all.

Comment: And now I'm throwing my hands up in the air because I get the same alert/error as above if I do try to install it. (I am assuming this means it did try to install it automatically.)

Answer (score -1):

Turn off wifi.  Reset All settings.  Phone reboots and download is canceled.